# Minimal polynomial of a field extension implies the powers of indeterminate are linearly independent

Tags: field-theory, minimal-polynomials

Suppose $L:K$ is a field extension and $a \in L$ is algebraic over $K$ with minimal polynomial $m(a) \in K[x]$?

I have written in my notes that:

If $d=deg(m(a))$ then $\{1,x,x^2, \ldots , x^d\}$ is a linearly independent set.

Where does this come from? Isn’t it always an independent set as $x$ is just an indeterminate?

Comment: It's supposed to be $\{1, a,a^2, \ldots , a^{d-1}\}$

Comment: Actually I think it is supposed to be $\{1, a, a^2, \ldots, a^{d - 1} \}$

Comment: @RobertLewis Very true. And corrected.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, I think your result is misquoted. It is most likely supposed to be

> If $\deg(m(a)) = d$, then $\{1,a,a^2, \ldots , a^{d-1}\}$ is a linearly independent set over $K$

If $\{1,a,a^2, \ldots , a^{d-1}\}$ were linearly dependent over $K$, then that would mean that there is a non-trivial linear combination of these elements that equals $0$:
$$
k_0 + k_1a + k_2a^2 + \cdots + k_{d-1}a^{d-1} = 0, \qquad k_i\in K, \text{not all }0
$$
This runs directly counter to the fact that the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K$ has degree $d$, as
$$
k_0 + k_1x + k_2x^2 + \cdots + k_{d-1}x^{d-1}
$$
would be a non-zero polynomial of lesser degree with $a$ as root.

Comment: My notes say $x$‘s and that then the cosets of these elements in the L.I set form a basis for the quotient field $K[x] / (m(a))$. And therefore $\{1,a,...,a^{d-1}\}$ is a basis for $K(a):K$. This really is not clear to me.

Comment: @Anteater23 If you want an explanation to how field extensions work (and from your comment, it sounds like that's what you're after), then that's really a chapter or two in any introductory algebra book. I don't think I can explain all of that in a comment, or even as an edit to my answer.

Comment: I fully understand your answer! I’m just confused about the $x$ part in my notes and why the set of cosets of these powers of $x$ provides basis for the quotient field.